# Transpose individual cells in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

Here is the image of the dataframe:

[image: Transposing cells in R dataframe]

I have this data frame from a cognitive psych task in which people respond to shapes and sounds. They are meant to always respond in that order, but sometimes they switch but still respond correctly (see second last row for example). I can easily isolate those rows, but I want to transpose the response times so they are in the correct columns. In the example, 1628 which is the response time for the shape stimuli should be in column 'RT1' and the sound response 1462 should be in column 'RT2'.

What function or code can I use to transpose cells given row and column coordinates? Ideally I would use this in the context of an 'if' statement to select the rows in which the responses are transposed.

Hope this makes sense. I cant share the actual data frame.

Comment: Although you can't share the actual data, you could make a small fake data set indicating  the problem and also what the intended result is.  I don't think you mean transpose, which has a specific meaning in R (and linear algebra).  Do you mean switch?

Comment: To transpose a dataset in R, you could use `t()` as a function

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks - Elin, yes, I mean to switch the cells which represent the RTs which are in the wrong column. Working on making fake data, but that could take some time. Really just want to know how to change particular cells in a data frame

Comment: Is the only condition that `Type1 == SOUND`? Do only `RT1` and `RT2` get swapped? What about `Shp.Res` and `Snd.Res`? If so, then `idx <- type1 == "SOUND"` identifies the rows that need to be swapped.

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. Yes, only RT1 and RT2 get swapped for those trials were Type 1 = Sound. The other columns are not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks something like this:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  Type1 = c("SHAPE", "SHAPE", "SOUND", "SHAPE"),
  Type2 = c("SOUND", "SOUND", "SHAPE", "SOUND"),
  RT1 = 10 + 1:4,
  RT2 = 20 + 1:4)
```

## Base R

```r
swaps <- dat$Type1 == "SOUND" & dat$Type2 == "SHAPE"
tmp1 <- dat$Type2[swaps]
dat$Type2[swaps] <- dat$Type1[swaps]
dat$Type1[swaps] <- tmp1
tmp1 <- dat$RT2[swaps]
dat$RT2[swaps] <- dat$RT1[swaps]
dat$RT1[swaps] <- tmp1
dat
#   Type1 Type2 RT1 RT2
# 1 SHAPE SOUND  11  21
# 2 SHAPE SOUND  12  22
# 3 SHAPE SOUND  23  13
# 4 SHAPE SOUND  14  24
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  mutate(
    swaps = Type1 == "SOUND" & Type2 == "SHAPE",
    tmp = if_else(swaps, Type2, Type1),
    Type2 = if_else(swaps, Type1, Type2),
    Type1 = tmp,
    tmp = if_else(swaps, RT2, RT1),
    RT2 = if_else(swaps, RT1, RT2),
    RT1 = tmp
  ) %>%
  select(-tmp)
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[ Type1 == "SOUND" & Type2 == "SHAPE",
    c("Type1", "Type2", "RT1", "RT2") := .(Type2, Type1, RT2, RT1) ]
```

Comment: Using `within` and `ifelse`, base R can mirror dplyr: https://rextester.com/IFAGJ93154

Comment: Certainly, `transform` can be used as well.